# CouchDB 1.3.1 on Centos 6.4

Tags: erlang, centos, couchdb, x86-64, spidermonkey

I compiled CouchDB and installed. It seems to work great except when I use views on the database, then it just spins the wheel and nothing happens and the cpu load spikes to 100% and slowly it eats away all memory and starts to swap a lot which in return increases the cpu load.

I have tried both with the js-1.70-12 that comes with centos 6.4, as well as build and install my own js-1.85-1. All erlang packages are installed from epel :

```
erlang-crypto-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-syntax_tools-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-mnesia-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-ssl-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosProperty-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-asn1-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosEventDomain-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-eunit-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-erl_docgen-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-toolbar-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-debugger-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-tools-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-typer-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-megaco-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-oauth-1.1.1-1.el6.x86_64
erlang-stdlib-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-hipe-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-kernel-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-runtime_tools-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-snmp-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-public_key-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-inets-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-ibrowse-2.2.0-4.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosEvent-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosNotification-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-edoc-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-otp_mibs-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosFileTransfer-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosTransactions-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-inviso-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-jinterface-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-erl_interface-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-diameter-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-gs-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-tv-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-appmon-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-odbc-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-wx-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-et-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-observer-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-sasl-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-dialyzer-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-common_test-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-os_mon-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-examples-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-compiler-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-erts-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-xmerl-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-orber-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-cosTime-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-ssh-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-docbuilder-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-percept-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-parsetools-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-ic-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-pman-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-webtool-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-test_server-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-reltool-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-R14B-04.2.el6.x86_64
erlang-mochiweb-1.4.1-5.el6.x86_64
```

Every thing configures and makes and installs as expected. You can dump data into the database, you can create documents and all that. But I can not run any view, temporary or not.

The only error I see in the logs is like this one, and it is a lot of these errors :

```
[Sun, 18 Aug 2013 23:10:38 GMT] [error] [<0.124.0>] {error_report,<0.30.0>,
                    {<0.124.0>,crash_report,
                     [[{initial_call,
                           {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                       {pid,<0.124.0>},
                       {registered_name,[]},
                       {error_info,
                           {exit,eaddrinuse,
                               [{gen_server,init_it,6},
                                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                       {ancestors,
                           [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,
                            <0.31.0>]},
                       {messages,[]},
                       {links,[<0.93.0>]},
                       {dictionary,[]},
                       {trap_exit,true},
                       {status,running},
                       {heap_size,987},
                       {stack_size,24},
                       {reductions,459}],
                      []]}}
```

But I have no idea what they mean.

Do I need to compile and install erlang as well ? All the above packages or just erlang ?

Comment: This compiles and runs without any issues on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation and installation looks fine. At least your error (note: `eaddrinuse` in traceback) is about that there is some process that listens same address and port as your CouchDB try to. Check other listening processes with `netstat -anp` command or change CouchDB's listen port to different.

Comment: That isn't it. The error file is really big, not sure about posting this here. But on the same computer if I install the centos couchdb 1.0.4, everything works. That seems to be the issue. I don't know erlang so these error messages look very cryptic

Comment: TL;DR @kxepal is correct. This error means that there is more than one process trying to bind to the same IP address / port combo.